# How to disaplay relation data on update action backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, eloquent-relationship

Making CRUD on Backpack for Laravel, and got issue.
I have Domain and domainPrices table
Domain model:

```
public function domainPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DomainPrices::class, 'domain_id', 'id');
}
```

DomainPrices model:

```
public function domain()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Domain::class, 'id', 'domain_id');
}
```

Migration:

```
    Schema::table('domain_prices', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('domain_id')->references('id')->on('domains')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

For setupCreateOperation()

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'bin_price',
    'type' => 'number',
    'entity' => 'domainPrice',
    'attribute' => 'bin_price',
    'model' => 'DomainPrices',
    'pivot' => false,
]);
```

setupUpdateOperation:

```
$this->setupCreateOperation();
```

And I'm able to store data with this, but when I use update route, there is empty field.
But it is display the value, on list view with:

```
CRUD::column('domainPrice')->attribute('bin_price');
```

[image]

PHP VERSION: PHP 8.0.5

LARAVEL VERSION: v8.44.0

BACKPACK VERSION: 4.1.46

Answer (score 1):

Solution was more easy than I though
Instead of:

```
    $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'bin_price',
        'type' => 'number',
        'entity' => 'domainPrice',
        'attribute' => 'bin_price',
        'model' => 'DomainPrices',
        'pivot' => false,
    ]);
```

I use:

```
    $this->crud->field('domainPrice.bin_price');
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the solution in case you are trying to create/update a 1:1 child record, from the parent create/edit form:

Parent Model:

```
public function child(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Child::class);
}
```

Child Model:

```
public function parent(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
}
```

Parent CRUD Controller:

```
CRUD::field('child')->type('relationship')
    ->label('Child Label')
    ->subfields($arrayOfFields);
```

Make sure, you import the inline form trait in the child crud controller

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;
```

*(Laravel Backpack 5.x)*